# How to specify index.mapping.ignore_malformed setting using NEST in ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

Is it possible to specify **index.mapping.ignore_malformed** setting using ElasticSearch NEST client? I am not able to find any docs or visible api methods to access this setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Index settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-malformed.html#ignore-malformed-setting) can be specified using `.Settings()`. The client has methods for known extensions, and any other settings can be specified using `.Setting(string setting, object value)`

```
var client = new ElasticClient();

client.CreateIndex("my_index", c => c
    .Settings(s => s
        .Setting("index.mapping.ignore_malformed", true)
    )
);
```

You can also specify `ignore_malformed` on a per field basis too.